# unable to run sql file in ubuntu command line

Tags: sql, oracle

I have typed the following query in command line and it worked but when I try to run it through the command @..../filename.sql the first query works but the second doesn't...I can't figure out why. need help.
Also the Error message I am getting reads
SP2-0042 Unknown command ")" - rest of line ignored

here is the query

```
/** Query 1: works through terminal and by calling @.../filename.sql**/

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
( cID   NUMBER NOT NULL,
  firstName     VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  lastName  VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  streetAddress VARCHAR2(50),
    CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PK PRIMARY KEY (customerID) 
);

/**Query2: only works through terminal**/

CREATE TABLE ADDRESS
( 
  cID   NUMBER NOT NULL,
  city          VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  zipCode       VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS FOREIGN KEY (cID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(cID) ON UPDATE CASCADE

);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it's not working? Does it produce an error message? Or is it just ignored?

Comment: the Error message I am getting reads SP2-0042 Unknown command ")" - rest of line ignored

Answer (score 1):

SQL Plus doesn't like empty lines in the middle of DDL (for non-procedural objects). Remove the empty line before the closing parenthesis or run `set sqlblanklines on` before running that DDL.

Comment: I tried set sqlblanklines on and also removed the blank line before the end parenthesis and it produced another error message this time ORA-00905: missing keyword

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not support `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, it only supports `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#CJAIHHGC

So apart from the empty line (that Allan already pointed out), you need to remove the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` for the foreign key.